Power BI Average measure seems to ignore dates
I am new to both Power BI and Stack Overflow, but I am having a bit of trouble getting an AVERAGE measure to work on my data in Power BI.
I have a table of products with pricing for myself and the difference in price for two competitors, and I have a date slicer which uses the date of the corresponding Monday for each date. I want my table to show the average price difference for each competitor during the week selected in the slicer.
The problem is that upon selecting a week date in the slicer, the average values for Competitor 1 and Competitor 2 are not correct.
I have created a measure for each competitor that looks like this:
Most Recent Diff Competitor 1 = 
VAR MinDate = MIN('Calendar'[WeekStartDate])
VAR MostRecentDate = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(pricetracker_price_history[date]),
        REMOVEFILTERS('Calendar'[WeekStartDate]),
        pricetracker_price_history[date]<MinDate,
        pricetracker_price_history[Competitor 1]<>BLANK()
    )
VAR MostRecentDiff = 
    IF(
        AVERAGE(pricetracker_price_history[Competitor 1])<>BLANK(),
        AVERAGE(pricetracker_price_history[Competitor 1]),
        IF(MostRecentDate<>BLANK(),
            CALCULATE(
                AVERAGE(pricetracker_price_history[Competitor 1]),
                REMOVEFILTERS('Calendar'[WeekStartDate]),
                pricetracker_price_history[date]=MostRecentDate
            ),
            COUNTBLANK(pricetracker_price_history[Competitor 1])-COUNTBLANK(pricetracker_price_history[Competitor 1]) //This was to give 0 instead of blank spaces
        )
    )
RETURN MostRecentDiff

The idea is that if there is no price difference given in the table for a particular date, then the price difference should be taken as the most recent non-blank value prior to that date.
My tables look like this (truncated here):
pricetracker_price_history



sku
Date
My Price
Competitor 1
Competitor 2




12345
30/07/2024
£52
-£0.05
-£2.01


12345
29/07/2024
£52
-£0.05
-£2.01


12345
28/07/2024
£52
-£0.05
-£2.01


12345
27/07/2024
£52
-£0.05
-£2.01


12345
26/07/2024
£52
-£0.05
-£2.01


12345
25/07/2024
£52
-£0.05
-£2.01


12345
24/07/2024
£52
-£0.05
-£2.01


12345
23/07/2024
£52
-£0.05
-£2.01


12345
22/07/2024
£52
-£0.05
-£2.01


12345
21/07/2024
£52
-£0.05
-£2.01


12345
20/07/2024
£52
-£0.05
-£2.01


12345
19/07/2024
£52
-£0.05
-£2.01


12345
18/07/2024
£52
-£0.05
-£2.01


12345
17/07/2024
£52
-£0.05
-£2.01


12345
16/07/2024
£52
-£0.05
-£2.01


12345
15/07/2024
£52

-£5.06


12345
14/07/2024
£52

-£5.06


12345
13/07/2024
£52

-£5.06



Calendar



Date
WeekStartDate




30/07/2024
29/07/2024


29/07/2024
29/07/2024


28/07/2024
22/07/2024


27/07/2024
22/07/2024


26/07/2024
22/07/2024


25/07/2024
22/07/2024


24/07/2024
22/07/2024


23/07/2024
22/07/2024


22/07/2024
22/07/2024


21/07/2024
15/07/2024


20/07/2024
15/07/2024


19/07/2024
15/07/2024


18/07/2024
15/07/2024


17/07/2024
15/07/2024


16/07/2024
15/07/2024


15/07/2024
15/07/2024


14/07/2024
08/07/2024


13/07/2024
08/07/2024



Upon selecting WeekStartDate as 22/07/2024 in the slicer, the visualisation gives:



sku
Competitor 1 Average
Competitor 2 Average




12345
-£2.06
-£4.45



when I would expect it to be



sku
Competitor 1 Average
Competitor 2 Average




12345
-£0.05
-£2.01



I'm struggling to see why the average is not being taken over just the dates with WeekStartDate = 22/07/2024.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I think you should get the correct answer.
Have you create the relationship between two tables (Connecting date columns)

Then create two measures
Measure = AVERAGE(pricetracker_price_history[Competitor 1])
measure2 = average(pricetracker_price_history[Competitor 2])



Hi Ryan, I have created the relationship on date, however it is one-to-many as the pricetracker_price_history table includes the same data for other products as well so there are multiple entries for each date.
Checking it now, the relationship wasn't 'active', I think because the calendar had an existing relationship with a sales table. Changing this setting seems to have resolved the issue! Many thanks for your assistance!
